# Call to undefined function

Tags: php, function, oop

I am trying to call a method from a different class in a different file.  However, When I run the code i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function getFxRate() in fxCalc.php

Here is the code I am trying to build:

**fxCalc.php**

```
//call fxDataModel class
require_once('fxDataModel.php');
$fxRate = getFxRate($inputCurrency, $outputCurrency);
$txtOutput = $txtInput * $fxRate;
```

**fxDataModel.php**

```
   public static function getFxRate($inputCurrency, $outputCurrency)
    {
        $fxRate = $currencies[$inputCurrency][$outputCurrency];
        return $fxRate;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The function `getFxRate()` is a static method of another class. You need to call it as `OtherClassName::getFxRate($inputCurrency, $outputCurrency)`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think that would be a better answer than a comment

Comment: [The docs on how `static` methods are scoped and called...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say if your name of the class in`fxDataModel.php` is `FxModel`

Then you need to call your method like

`$fxRate = FxModel::getFxRate($inputCurrency, $outputCurrency);`

instead of

`$fxRate = getFxRate($inputCurrency, $outputCurrency);`

That is because your function is declared as `static`. The static calls are made by using `::` operator followed by the class name.